# ASP.NET Core 6/7 MVC with TypeScript using export and import causes errors

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc

How can you configure a simple ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project to use TypeScript, specifically allowing you to import and export packages?

I have spent a lot of time attempting to add TypeScript to an (existing or new) ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application, but I hit a brick wall every time I try to export or import a library. I have attempted too many config settings to list here, a lot of googling and research, but no luck.

Typically the code compiles, but running in the browser I get errors like (depending on the module) "Exports is not defined" or "define is not defined". This will work if I pack all files into one (using Webpack), however I don't want to combine files, at least not in development.

I have tried multiple configurations, but currently tsconfig.json looks like:

```json
{ 
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",                              
    "module": "amd",                            
    "rootDir": "./scripts",                     
    "moduleResolution": "node",                 
    "sourceMap": true,                          
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/js/",                  
    "esModuleInterop": true,                    
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,   
    "strict": true,                             
    "skipLibCheck": true                        
  }
}
```

My test.ts looks like:

```
import convert from "convert";
export function add(x: number, y: number): number
{
    return x + y;
}
```

The browser error reads "Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined"

I have added my code to GitHub for reference: https://github.com/dwilliams459/typescript-mvc7-demo/tree/main

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you tried to install commonjs: `npm install @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`? There are many solutions for this kind of problem in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined), you can check it to see if there is one that suits you.

Comment: I have tired that particular post.  I have not installed that babel plugin yet, I will give that a try

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use `"module": "amd"`? If you consider using `"module": "commonjs"`, you will get `exports is not defined` which can be easily resolved.

Browsers don't support the CommonJS syntax (unless using a tool like webpack) of `require` and `module.exports`, which is causing the error.

Since you don't want to use tools like Webpack, you can try to define a global exports variable above the script tags that load your JS files:

```
<script>var exports = {};</script>
<script src="~/js/test.js"></script>

<script>
    alert(add(1,2));
</script>
```

This defines the `exports` variable and sets it to an empty object, so you won't get an error if properties are accessed on it.

If you must use `"module": "amd"`, you can try to [install amd-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675778/18789859).

Comment: I did try the var exports solution, but not the amd-loader.  I will also try that.